# How to serve HTTP 400 when missing Location parameters?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Consider this simple [ktor](https://ktor.io/) server setup

```kotlin
@Location("/user") data class User(val id: Long)

fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(Locations)
    routing {
        get<User> {
            call.respondText("User[id: ${id}]")
        }
    }
}
```

Getting `/user?id=123` works fine resulting in `User [id 123]`.

However getting `/user` yields `HTTP 404` but a `HTTP 400` make much more sense here.

How can I

1. Serve `400` instead of `404` in such case?
2. Attach a custom
   error handler for missing query parameters so I can provide clients
   with information about what they got wrong?

sidenote: I also filled [an issue](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1711) in the ktor github repository for this.

Thanks in advance!